# How to group language variants in Google Analytics' Users Flow

Tags: google-analytics, language

In [Google Analytics' Users Flow](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1709395), language variants such as `en-us` and `en-gb` are shown as different flows.

[image: Google Analytics users flow]

As my website&marketing does not differentiate between language variants, how to group variants in order to just have single flows `en`, `fr`, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize it by clicking settings ico (next to selected dimension).

Then you see:

[image: customize]

This setting can be saved using a browser bookmark, as customization details are in the URL.

**Matching "others"**

You can't exclude something from a match, but you can add *matching regexp* rule below.

[image: others]

Interpretation:

1. name 'english' every value from 'language' dimension which contains 'en'
2. name 'french' every value from 'language' dimension (subset without matches from first rule) which contains 'fr'
3. name 'others' every value from 'language' dimension (subset without matches from 1st and 2nd rule) which contains or not any char

About regexp in GA: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en

Comment: @nicolas-raoul I improved my answer. Now contains solution for others category